# Find largest, smallest, positive and negative

Tags: c++

I wrote this code and I want it to find the count of numbers that are negative, smallest number, largest number, average of the numbers, and sum of the number

It's not working, Could you help me using `if` statement? I can't find the smallest or largest (when numbers are negative) + can't find if all of numbers were negative or positive or mix.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    float num,
        average,
        sum,
        smallest,
        largest,
        positive,
        negative;

    int count;
    sum = 0;
    count = 1;
    largest = 0;
    smallest = 0;
    negative = 0;

    while (count < 11) {
        cout << "Number #" << count << ": ";
        cin >> num;

        if (num < 0) negative++;

        sum += num;
        average = (sum / 10);

        if (num > largest) largest = num;
        else if (num < smallest) smallest = num;

        count++;
    }

    cout << endl << "The smallest number is " << smallest << endl;
    cout << "The largest number is " << largest << endl;
    cout << "The average of all numbers is " << average << endl;
    cout << "The sum of all numbers is " << sum << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "There are " << negative << " negative numbers." << endl;


    if (num > 0) cout << "All numbers are positive.";
    else if (sum < 0) cout << "All numbers are negative.";
    else if {
        cout << "There is a mixture of numbers.";
    }
}
```

//------------------------------------
**EDIT**

I've made some changes and I almost got right, but I still can't find a way to find the smallest and largest

```
using namespace std;

void main()
{

float num,
average,
sum,
largest,
smallest,
positive,
negative;

int count;
sum = 0;
count = 1;
negative = 0;

largest= 0;
smallest = 0;

while ( count < 11)
{
  cout << "Number #" << count << ": ";
  cin >> num;

  if ( num < 0 )negative++;

  sum += num;

  if (count != 0 )
  {
     if ( num > largest )
        largest = num;
     else if ( num < smallest )
        smallest = num;
  }

  count++;
} 

average = ( sum / 10 );


cout << endl << "The smallest number is " << smallest << endl;
cout << "The largest number is " << largest << endl;
cout << "The average of all numbers is " << average << endl;
cout << "The sum of all numbers is " << sum << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "There are " << negative << " negative numbers." << endl;

 if ( negative == 0 )
    cout << "All numbers are positive.";
 else if ( negative == 10 )
    cout << "All numbers are negative.";
 else 
 {
    cout << "There is a mixture of numbers.";
 }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? You need to tell us that.

Comment: You need to compute average after you have the total sum. Have you considered storing the numbers in an array or `std::vector`? Can you use the `std::algorithm` library? Also, just because `sum < 0` does not mean that the all the numbers of negative. Imagine you have the numbers -321 and 52.

Comment: The problem is I haven't taken array or std::vector or even std::algorithm yet. which means I'm not allowed to use them in this program.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody spotted that your declarations including and starting at `count` all end with semi-colon so only the first declaration is explicitly declared as an integer.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur they aren't meant to be declarations but are just initializing the variable's values. An edit had mixed up the indentation.

Comment: I've tried to change things but it still doesn't work. it does everything but finding the smallest and the largest

Comment: Add a `cout` statement inside each of the tests to see how the values are getting treated. Add braces to be explicit about what goes with what. Get rid of the `else` - just run every test (efficiency isn't the first goal here). Let us know what you learn.

Comment: I think the problem is the first value of the largest and smallest which is 0. tried to change it around but nothing happend

Comment: As a matter of good practice you should set both `largest` and `smallest` equal to `num` in the first iteration, and update them when `count>1`. But that's not your issue I think.

Comment: yeah but It still fails to do it right. there has to be a mistake but I really can't find it.

Comment: What happens when you put a `cout` inside each `if` statement?

Comment: nothing happens, what I decided to do is to set high value for the smallest and largest, it worked but the problem it didn't work when finding whether the numbers are negative or positive or mix

Comment: I have updated my answer with code that tested and worked fine on my machine. Let me know if your output is not the same as mine.

Answer (score 2):

You should not compute the average until you have all the numbers; or if you want to keep a running average, you have to divide by the sum you have so far.  So instead of the line

```
average = sum / 10;
```

In the middle of your loop, try

```
average = sum / count;
```

while inside the loop, or

```
average = sum / (count - 1);
```

After the loop. Of course since you don't actually *use* the average until the loop is completed, it doesn't actually matter - but it's a bit sloppy.

Next, your code

```
if ( num > 0 )
   cout << "All numbers are positive.";
else if ( sum  < 0 )
   cout << "All numbers are negative.";
```

Has two obvious bugs. First - you check whether "num" is positive - that's the last number entered, not "all the numbers". And the sum will be negative if you had one very negative number. Instead use your count of negative numbers:

```
if ( negative == 0) // all positive
if ( negative == 10) // all negative
```

Otherwise, it's a mixture. I am sure you can fix your code with these pointers.

**EDIT #2**

I decided to implement all the changes I had mentioned above, plus the ones I mentioned in comments, in a complete program.  The code I ended up with is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

float num,
  average,
  sum=0,
  largest=0,
  smallest=0,
  positive=0,
  negative=0;

int count=1;

negative = 0;

while ( count < 11)
{
  cout << "Number #" << count << ": ";
  cin >> num;

  if ( num < 0 ) negative++;

  sum += num;

  if (count == 1) {
    largest = num;
    smallest = num;
  }
  else {
     if ( num > largest )
        largest = num;
     if ( num < smallest )
        smallest = num;
  }

  count++;
}

average = ( sum / (count - 1) );


cout << endl << "The smallest number is " << smallest << endl;
cout << "The largest number is " << largest << endl;
cout << "The average of all numbers is " << average << endl;
cout << "The sum of all numbers is " << sum << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "There are " << negative << " negative numbers." << endl;

if ( negative == 0 )
  cout << "All numbers are positive."<<endl;
else if ( negative == 10 )
  cout << "All numbers are negative."<<endl;
else
{
  cout << "There is a mixture of numbers.";
}

}
```

This compiles fine; and when I run it and enter the following inputs:

```
Number #1: 5
Number #2: 4
Number #3: 3
Number #4: 2
Number #5: 1
Number #6: 0
Number #7: -1
Number #8: -2
Number #9: -3
Number #10: -4
```

I get this output:

```
The smallest number is -4
The largest number is 5
The average of all numbers is 0.5
The sum of all numbers is 5

There are 4 negative numbers.
There is a mixture of numbers.
```

Looks to me like it's working. Does it work for you?

Comment: The `float` variables aren't declared twice, they are declared and the initialized. The edited indentation made it look like they were part of the `int` declaration.

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work with all negative numbers. is the problem with the if statement before testing?

Comment: @davidbrown thanks for catching that.